# WordPress: Reset password always invalid key

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a huge problem and can't find the solution. I've installed the Ultimate Member Plugin and activated it. ^

When I reset now the password for a user I'm getting an email from my page with a reset link generated in the `class-password.php` file of the plugin triggered by the UM function call `um_user( 'password_reset_link' )` which triggers this function :

```
/**
 * Get Reset URL
 *
 * @return bool|string
 */
function reset_url() {
    $user_id = um_user( 'ID' );
    delete_option( "um_cache_userdata_{$user_id}" );
    //new reset password key via WP native field
    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $key = get_password_reset_key( $user_data );
    $url =  add_query_arg( array( 'act' => 'reset_password', 'hash' => $key, 'user_id' => $user_id ), um_get_core_page( 'password-reset' ) );
    return $url;
}
```

To check the hash I've added an `error_log` in the function `get_password_reset_key` located in the `users.php` file from WordPress to log the generated hashes by the key:

```
error_log( $hashed );
```

I've also added the same hasher into the email template from Ultimate Member and this was the result:

```
[23-Dec-2018 15:57:41 UTC] 1545580661:$P$BiLzjLuPDHwVtUlnLmEQE19D4UpgJf0
[23-Dec-2018 15:57:41 UTC] 1545580661:$P$BCAl/MTbiuCyqiix7310EOEn.eJlQz1
[23-Dec-2018 15:57:41 UTC] 1545580661:$P$BH0W.btK4hYFNDidKh.DA46KZhp5Ay.
[23-Dec-2018 15:57:41 UTC] Hash from mail: 1545580661:$P$BOzHQ9mIasqhbdYnkK0n.EXhGXBFyD0
[23-Dec-2018 15:57:41 UTC] 1545580661:$P$BGRg8guQBbhuNKdMCIDSweNUDKLG1v/
```

So as you can see there are 4 hashes generated by WordPress and the one generated from the returned `key` directly in the email.

When I save now the generated hash in the email into the `users` table value for the field `user_activation_key` and press the reset button, I'm able to change the password.

So why is the hash generated not correctly and how can I fix this? I mean I can change the function and generate a new hash and write it again into the database but this can't be the solution.

Comment: The activation key don't get's updated correctly. Don't know why. I'm doing further researches.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @itsdanprice Yes, I did. Do you have a problem with this?

Comment: Yeah - same as described. It's not generating the email correctly - despite having html email selected. I'm limiting password resets. The reset link always leads to invalid key.

Comment: Are you using UltimateMember too? If yes, how did you get the reset link in your email for resetting the password?

Comment: @Mr.Jo If you solved it could please post your answer rather than being defensive.

Answer (score 4):

What fixed my issue with UM Password Reset stating "Invalid Key" was disabling any caching on my `/password-reset` page. Not sure if this would fix your issue, but in case any one else comes here.

Comment: We had the same problem with the set up: Wordpress, WooCommerce, Woocommerce Memberships, WPS Hide Login and the Sucuri Firewall/WAF. Disabeling the cache on the firewall for the custom login page solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone staill has this problem with or without the plugin,
check the reset link in email.
In my example link was

```
<https://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=XXsomehashXX&login=username>
```

the url was generated with the character `>` at the end and
in a browser it looked like this

```
https://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=XXsomehashXX&login=username%3E
```

All it took to fix this was delete the `%3E` at the end of url and password reset form was functioning!

Comment: You are amazing!